# Choosing a robot for beginners on ROS

Tags: ros, roomba, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am in the process of getting myself a cheap research robot for experimenting and learning with ROS. I identified the Roomba series of vacuum cleaners as the most economical in terms of price and what I am looking to do with it using ROS.

The 'Roomba create' would be a good option if ROS had drivers for it already. Though, I don't think I would be able to get my hands on it since I live outside the US and iRobot does not ship 'Roomba create' outside the US.

So bottom line,

1. I would like to know, which series of Roomba cleaners are outright supported by ROS without me having to write drivers to integrate it with ROS?
2. What are some interesting things that can be done with a Roomba bot and ROS? I am just looking for ideas. Even fringe ideas are welcome : )

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10288/choosing-a-robot-for-beginners-on-ros/) by [kissandra79](https://answers.ros.org/users/648/kissandra79/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2011-06-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Create  has excellent ROS support; There are [many driver implementations](http://www.ros.org/browse/search.php?q=create)

The most actively developed at the moment is the TurtleBot driver.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-07-05**:
We now have an alternative on turtlebot.eu

**Comment by [kissandra79](https://answers.ros.org/users/648/kissandra79/) on 2011-06-17**:
Maybe it does.. but unfortunately, they do not ship the create to places outside the US

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can go on ebay and search for "Roomba". There are a lot of peaple that has bought the Roomba just for "impulse" but maybe it becomes useless. I'm in Italy e I've found one for €70,00...

I think that all the 500 series is supported. [Take a look here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Roomba). There is a step-by-step very easy to follow of how to assembly and use things like an onboard [arduino](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arduino), a laser scanner, kinnect, and such like that.

You'll impress your boyfriend with those things... :D

---

Originally posted by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) with karma: 482 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on 2011-06-19**:
There is a roomba on my lab at the universitỳ so I did just some "stupid" things to understand how it works, like a simple teleoperation. I'm beginning with ros too. We intend to work with embedded sistems.

**Comment by [kissandra79](https://answers.ros.org/users/648/kissandra79/) on 2011-06-18**:
May I ask what you did with your roomba? Did you manage to integrate it with ROS? Or did you do something else that is completely different?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are trying hard to get everything up and running on turtlebot.eu. Currently we are creating our webshop and setting up logistics. I hope we'll be able to provide you with a solution soon.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2